# VideoVIew issue on android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am working on video player in android.when i created surface holder in on create method ,it did not create.but when i created the surface holder in button onclick method,its created

My coding is,

```
preview=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
    preview.setEnabled(true);
    preview.bringToFront();
    holder=preview.getHolder();
    holder.setFixedSize(400, 400);

    mp=new MediaPlayer(); 
    mp.setDataSource("path");
    mp.setDisplay(holder);
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(playerActivity.this);
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(playerActivity.this);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

prepare() is asynchronous, which means, it might not be finished when you already call the mp.start. What do you mean by 'surface not created'? Do you just mean the video doesn't play?
Anyway, you should use an `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener` and start the media in `onPrepared()`.